# Placement des adverbes dans une phrase négative

Tags: négation, ordre-des-mots, indications-de-temps, adverbes

I'm a brazilian living in Paris for 1 year. I have some doubts about the order of words: In portuguese we're kind of flexible regarding the order of some words, I'll try to explain using an example, the following 3 ways of saying **I didn't eat yet** are acceptable (Eu = I, comi=did eat, não = not, ainda = yet):

- Eu não comi ainda
- Eu ainda não comi
- Eu comi ainda não (some parts of Brazil)

Now, I don't really know what are the possible orders in french, or which of them sounds weird for french people. Are both 'Je n'ai pas mangé encore' and 'Je n'ai pas encore mangé' allowed? What about 'I haven't even eat yet', "Je n'ai même pas encore mangé?"? Is there a rule or a way to think about this, at least for adverbs/locutions adverbiales(?) like même, encore, du tout?

Answer (score 6):

Je pense que les 2 sont autorisées, mais la plus correcte et celle qu'on entendra le plus souvent est :

> Je n'ai pas encore mangé.

Quant à l'ajout de "even", tu peux effectivement dire :

> Je n'ai même pas encore mangé.

Remarque, il est aussi possible de placer "encore" de cette façon :

> Je n'ai encore pas mangé.

Mais la signification sera différente, "encore" n'aura plus le même sens que "yet" mais il aura plutôt le sens de "une nouvelle fois". Il sous-entend qu'il est déjà arrivé dans le passé que je ne mange pas, et que c'est à nouveau le cas.

Comment: dans le 3ème exemple, `toujours` serait plus approprié que `encore`. `Je n'ai toujours pas mangé.`

Comment: @ibiza Non. « Je n'ai encore pas mangé » et « je n'ai toujours pas mangé » n'ont pas du tout le même sens. « Encore pas » signifie une répétition : avant-hier je n'ai pas déjeuné, hier je n'ai pas déjeuné, aujourd'hui il est 15h et je n'ai encore pas mangé. « Toujours pas » est proche de « pas encore » mais signifie qu'il y a un retard anormal : je mange d'habitude entre 12h et 13h ; aujourd'hui il est 12h30 et je n'ai pas encore mangé ; plus tard il est 13h30 et je n'ai toujours pas mangé.

Comment: @Gilles Le "ne" n'est-il pas de trop dans la 3ème phrase ? Avec cette construction, pour moi la phrase serait "J'ai encore pas mangé"...

Comment: @Random En français familier, on omet le *ne*, mais pas en français soutenu.

Answer (score 3):

> - Je n'ai pas encore mangé
> - Je n'ai même pas encore mangé

... sont les expressions les plus usitées.

*[pas mangé encore](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=pas%20mang%C3%A9%20encore&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=)* ne renvoie aucune réponse, alors que [*mangé encore*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%20mang%C3%A9%20encore&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmang%C3%A9%20encore%3B%2Cc0) en renvoie quelques unes, il y a donc un problème de contexte à prendre en compte pour obtenir le bon ordre des mots .

La recherche de *[pas mangé du tout](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=pas%20mang%C3%A9%20du%20tout&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpas%20mang%C3%A9%20du%20tout%3B%2Cc0)* est différente, *du tout* peut indiquer qu'il ne s'est rien passé et que l'on n'est pas dans l'attente de quelque chose (contrairement à *encore*).